# Directory.Exists sensible to time?

Tags: c#, io, directory

I have the following piece of code in my application:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(myPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);
```

If I run it in a regular unit test sometimes it passes, sometimes not. The directory is always there (I made sure of it, so technically it will never be "created" by code). But every once in a while `Directory.Exists(myPath)` returned `false`, which makes the code try to create the folder and then I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`!

The funny thing here is if I put a breakpoint on the `CreateDirectory`, and then move the yellow arrow up back to test, the test returns `true`!

What's going on?

`myPath` is `\\nameOfLocalMachine\sharedFolder`. The share is reliable and constantly used... .NET 4.0

I just made a fiddler simulate 3000 sequentials requests. 175 failed... All with the same message:

> Access to the path '\nameOfLocalMachine\sharedFolder\randomFileName.json' is denied

Comment: I have the same 2 lines in production code. Didnt came across this though

Comment: Which version of windows, .NET, and is the path going to a local, UNC, or mapped drive?

Comment: there is problem with myPath there is no other explanation, debug it an check.

Comment: @mybirthname actually theres not... might is fixed and if there was/is everything should fail, and not 1.75 requests every hundred...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mishap is pretty normal on Windows.  Programs open a handle on a directory like this and specify *delete sharing*.  Which permits anybody to delete the directory, even though the program is using it.  The directory won't actually disappear from the file system until that handle is closed.  What follows is that trying to recreate that directory cannot work, it still exists.  Windows generates an "access denied" error, reported in your C# program with the UnauthorizedAccessException.

While that sounds like an obscure feature, *every* program in Windows does this.  Every process has a default working directory, the value of Environment.CurrentDirectory.  Creating a handle on such a directory ensures that it cannot disappear while the program is using it.  There are other cases, FileSystemWatcher would be another example.  Or a program busy iterating the directory.  Anti-malware and search indexers are notorious for hard to diagnose sources of such errors.

Otherwise a standard hazard of a multi-tasking operating system.  You are not the only one using the file system.  Not repeatedly deleting and creating the same directory ought to be very high on your list.  If this is absolutely necessary then *rename* the directory first before you delete it.  You'd still fail to delete the renamed directory but you won't fail recreating it.  You can delete it later, next time you need to do this.  Much lower odds for trouble then.  Because more time passed.